# How does a Cosmic String accelerate a Black Hole?

Tags: black-holes, cosmic-string

I've read that a Cosmic String could accelerate a Black Hole, but I'm not exactly sure how that works. Is the Black Hole pulled along the length of the String? I've also heard it could accelerate stars.

Would a Cosmic String accelerate a spacecraft, or would that not work for some reason?